# Get Julia version from Python script

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the Julia version from a python script.

```
C:\Users> julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.0.3 (2018-12-18)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |
|__/                   |

julia> VERSION
v"1.0.3"

julia> exit()
C:\Users>
```

This is the way I do it in CMD.

Looking for a way to access this version value using python.

When `using os.system('julia')` it never exits this stage because I guess it is waiting for a command within this Julia environment.

Comment: Does [running `julia --version`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4760215/11082165) and parsing the output fit your needs?

Comment: Yes sir, that works, I didn't consider trying it with dashes, thanks!

Comment: BTW, `subprocess.Popen(['julia'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stder=subprocess.PIPE).communicate('VERSION\nexit()\n')` is the closer equivalent to your original, but `--version` is very much the Right Thing.

Comment: `os.system()` is the wrong tool in no small part because it isn't designed to let you capture stdout at all in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I see, but that command might help me later on in capturing the version for containerized processes I have running. 

Yeah, I figured I was missing something when using os for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the julia interpreter's [command-line option](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/command-line-options/) `-v` in the shell:

```bash
julia -v
```

This system command can also be invoked from within Python using e.g. `subprocess`:

```py
version_output = subprocess.check_output(['julia', '-v'])
print(version_output)
```

See [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)